# How to use two one property of diffrent data type in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have a class in which i create object of class.Now i have a property `image` of object.What i am doing is i am getting some data from server & then i am setting the value of the image of object.Now when i get data from server then value of image will be a string but if i get value from any other source such image of contact then i will get the value of image as `UIImage`.Now want a comman data type by which i can save the value of image does not matter from which source the image is coming.

Comment: I think you should NSData instead of UIImage or String.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 'id' type for your variable.

```
id var;
var = @"string";
var = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];


if ([var isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // it's string
}
else if ([var isKindOfClass:[UIImage class]])
{
    // it's UIImage
}
```